# oracle pro*c query execution with placeholder columns put as null slowing down execution

Tags: sql, c, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-pro-c

We have the following query to execute to read bulk set of records:

```
SELECT  c1, c2, c3 , ........, c30, null,null,null,...,null 
FROM TBL1 
WHERE C5 = 5 
ORDER BY c7, c8
```

Note that extra null values have been put to accommodate query done in a generic manner, because `TBL1` may have 30 or more columns, and extra columns we need to capture separately as generic storage.

```
EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR DO ...;
EXEC SQL DECLARE xx CURSOR FOR xxx;     
EXEC SQL OPEN xxx;
EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND goto notfound;
EXEC SQL FETCH xxx INTO :a1:a1_ind, :a2:a2_ind;
```

where `a1`, `a2` are arrays of structures and `a1_ind`, `a2_ind` are arrays of indicator variables.

But the query takes a lot of time to execute, if I remove the indicator variables, then it's faster and possibly extra nulls too, but since I don't know how many extra column buffers needed, have to keep this way.
Any suggestions for improvement?